# How do i type special character like ' " : or ; when typing in Indian keyboard

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I am learning hindi typing using mangal font in Indian keyboard (Inscript). The problem is i am unable to find special character like `'`, `"`, `;`, or `:` . Also i did not found `ड़` too, in typing test if i type `ड़` as `ड + ़ = ड़` it does not work.

On google i found some code to type that special character but that is not working for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This](http://sites.psu.edu/symbolcodes/languages/southasia/devanagari/devanagarichart/#about) link enlists all the symbols used in Devanagari writing system. You won't find some of the characters on the keyboard.

To type such special characters  you need to remember alt code for Windows OS. To do the same in Linux based OSs, you need to remember hex code or OS X option code.

For example: the hexcode of Sanskrit symbol OUM is 950. So in order to type it in Linux you need to "press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> and release <kbd>u</kbd> but don't release <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>, now type the code <kbd>9</kbd><kbd>5</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>. After you have finished release <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>, you will see the desired symbol ॐ".

Now coming to your problem, you are typing in Hindi but want insert `'` and `"` since Devanagri don't have such symbols because these symbols came from latin script. So to insert it in our document we need to remember hex code of this character that come from latin so we first find code of this character and then press ctrl+shift+u, release u + desired code. You can see hex code of latin from [here](https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0000.pdf)

This method works in any languguage doesn't matter what language you are typing. I have found that hex code of these characters codes are 27 and 22. So I am writing it using shortcut ctrl+shift+u-u+code, ' and " OK.

Comment: It works perfectily fine with english keyboard, but not working while using inscript keyboard. Can you please help?